# FollowMeMission.FollowMeHeading cannot be set?

Tags: dji-sdk

In the process of updating an app I noticed that the value for FollowMeHeading is included in the FollowMeMission but there appears to be no setter for the value.

There is an InitUserData but that takes a lat, lng and altitude (maybe it should take a LocationCoordinate3D??) however there appears to be no way to set the heading mode.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

SDK 4.6 has changed the ctor for FollowMeMission  to pass in the value for FollowMeHeading.

Unfortunately it also removed initData and changed to use the ctor (not bad but the change will require some code changes.

Comment: I wish DJI would be consistent and use LocationCoordinate2D and LocationCoordinate3D rather than sometimes pass lat/lng/alt and sometimes pass lat/lng